# Как в битриксе изменить массив $arResult['NAV_RESULT'] для правильной пагинации, при изменении массива товаров $arResult['ITEMS']

Tags: битрикс

В интернет-магазине телефонов, нужно было вынести торговые предложения в отдельные карточки товаров, т.е. в каталоге показывать отдельно: Xiaomi mi 2 Черный 32Гб, Xiaomi mi 2 Синий 32Гб  и т.д. 
Для этого, сначала, в файле result_modifier.php компонента catalog.section, перенес данные из массива offers, каждого товара у которого есть такой массив, в основной массив товаров $arResult['ITEMS']. И тут вылезла проблема с пагинацией, стоит выводить по 9 товаров на странице, но выводятся все торговые предложения 9 основных товаров, т.е. на одной странице может быть 20 товаров, на другой 26. 
Получается, что пагинация строится по другому массиву до исполнения файла result_modifier.php в файле class.php, но как там изменить этот массив? 
Вроде бы нашел, что данные о количестве страниц и массив элементов формируется в функции getElementList, объект $elementIterator, и там формируется массив из основных товаров, количество страниц для пагинации. Но как изменить, чтобы получался нужный массив из простых товаров и торговых предложений?

Answer (score 0):

А Вам не проще торговые предложения стделать основным каталогом ? Вам ведь не нужно получается сам товар а именно его "разновидности" и переделывать ничего не придется.
http://prntscr.com/odkfa6
Для чего вам представление в виде SKU ?

Comment: Извините, немного не понял. У меня сейчас есть основной каталог товаров, в котором есть простые товары и товары с торговыми предложениями http://prntscr.com/odv9ww  SKU используются для товаров с разным цветов и объемом памяти http://prntscr.com/odvb4x

Comment: Значит вам нужно и торговые предложения выводить и товары (которые без SKU) ?

Comment: Если так то какие я вижу проблемы. Первое это не возможность реализации пагинации так как у вас постоянно будет меняться количество товаров с SKU и без SKU. В таком случае я бы сделал "фальшивую" пагинацию. Выводить все товары на страницу, но раскрывать только тогда когда это нужно через JS. Но это очень нагружено будет для покупателя и для сео не очень.

Comment: Можно так же вывести все элементы но в JS массив на странице записать в него только ID элемента и подгружать AJAX сами товары.

Comment: Второе что я вижу это карточка товара или детальная страница товара. Как у Вас происходит переход на нее с SKU? Может быть я чего не знаю но по стандартной логике битрикса нужно чтобы был переход именно на товар, а все SKU обрабатываются JS самого битрикс

Comment: И вот по этому я предлагал просто взять и переделать Инфоблок с SKU в торговый каталог. А для товаров которые без SKU создать их.

Comment: То есть как бы сделал я, создал SKU для товаров которых просто идут товарами (без SKU) и переделал бы каталог который выгружается торговыми предложениями из 1С на основной каталог и использовал его для вывода.

Comment: Да, нужно выводить товары с SKU и без. Для перехода с каталога в карточку конкретного SKU добавляю к ссылкам параметр с id торгового предложения http://prntscr.com/odxnls, и на странице товара в JS проверяю наличие параметра в адресе и устанавливаю текущее торговое предложение, а дальше все стандартно. Вот как раз не понял как для товаров создать SKU?

Comment: Товар у вас выгружается из 1С? Если да то какая 1С?

Comment: Да, товар выгружается из 1С, но вот какая именно, сказать не могу, выгружают другие люди. Нужно торговые предложения создавать прямо в основном каталоге?

Comment: в вашем случае если оставлять логике которая у Вас сейчас то только использовать "фальшивую" пагинацию. То есть выводить сначала все ID и подгружать SKU и товары AJAX.

Comment: Нет вам нужно зайти в товар без SKU поменять его тип http://prntscr.com/odxvu3, появиться такая вкладка в товаре http://prntscr.com/odxw6a и можно будет создать. Но если вы так сделаете то при выгрузке из 1С эти SKU могут деактивироваться. по идее тем людям нужно сказать чтобы они создали характеристики у товаров в 1С. В 1С SKU это Номенклатура + Характеристика.

Comment: Но получается, что торговые предложения также попадают в массив OFFERS товара

Comment: Offers это и есть торговые предложения.

Comment: Вы создадите одну логику и вам проще будет. Вообще я бы подзапарился и не выводил стандартными методами а использовал ciblockelement:getlist и выбирал именно торговые предложения . Но только вопрос с фильтром остается, он работает по товарам сейчас у Вас. Я знаю лишь как фильтровать товар по SKU используя  getlist

Comment: Извините, что не понимаю) Изменил тип простого товара на товар с SKU http://prntscr.com/ody62m, добавил к нему предложение http://prntscr.com/ody6hw и получилось то же, что и было http://prntscr.com/ody7a6, это с переносом массива OFFERS в $arResult['ITEMS']

Comment: Да, похоже надо переписать пагинацию и фильтрацию

Comment: Ничего что ни понимаете, это нормально ) давайте так какая задача стоит ? Возможно вам нужно чтобы при переходе сразу выводилось торговое предложение которое человек выбрал находясь в основном каталоге .

Comment: Если воспользоваться методом фальшивой фильтрации то просто нужно будет сделать свой пагинатор так как фильтр сам будет отсеевать ненужные товары и SKU

Comment: Да, при переходе из каталогу, нужно чтобы открывалось то предложение, что было выбрано. А как сделать фальшивую фильтрацию?

Comment: А вам не подойдёт метод со стандартной логикой Битрикс выбором SKU в каталоге товаров и просто подставлять при выборе определенного SKU ID этого SKU ? Так как при выборе параметра на карточке каталога и так получается определенное SKU

Comment: да, сейчас так и работает, что подставляю ID конкретного SKU и открывается нужное, исходя из этого ID

Comment: Фальшивая пагинация это то что я описывал выше. Убираете ограничение по количеству товара в каталоге. Таким образом у вас будут все товары выводиться сразу и потом вы можете раскрывать только те карточки товара которые вам нужно. Это костыль но в вашем случае по другом ни как.

Comment: Но вы сейчас берете именно определенное SKU как карточку в каталоге , а я предлагаю оставить выбор как у Битрикс (стандартный) где ты на карточке в каталоге выбираешь (цвет, размер, модель и т.д.) у товара. При выборе уже как раз передавать в кнопку перейти на товар ID вашего выбранного SKU

Comment: а, пагинация, понял) Попробую ее реализовать, но всплыла проблема с умным фильтром, он не отсекает ненужные торговые предложения

Comment: Так как используется стандартный catalog.section и вы делаете всё в result_modifier.php все равно должна происходить фильтрация

Comment: Из за тех.задания не получится сделать в одной карточке, к сожалению

Comment: Тогда бы я посоветовал сейчас сделать костылем, а потом привести товар к одному виду (товар с SKU) почитать про ciblockelement:getlist () там можно и пагинацию сделать. Я уверен что можно и фильтровать торговые предложения по товарам. Чуть позже скину как фильтруются товару по SKU эти методом

Answer (score 0):

```
$floatfilter = ${$arParams['FILTER_NAME']};
$arFilter += $floatfilter;

if($floatfilter["OFFERS"]) {
    $arf = ['IBLOCK_ID' => 81];

    foreach($floatfilter["OFFERS"] as $key => $value) {
        $arf += array($key => $value);
    }

    $arFilter += array(
        'ID' => CIBlockElement::SubQuery('PROPERTY_CML2_LINK', $arf)
    );
}

$res = CIBlockElement::GetList( array(), $arFilter, false, array( ), $arSelect );
```

Вызов глобального фильтра
$floatfilter = ${$arParams['FILTER_NAME']};
Добавляем в фильтр подзапрос с параметрами
CIBlockElement::SubQuery('PROPERTY_CML2_LINK', $arf)
Где 'PROPERTY_CML2_LINK' - поле связывающее товар и SKU

Comment: а это где нужно вызывать?

Comment: Вместо catalog.section по сути тот код что я написал будет заменять выборку компонента

Comment: а переменная $arFilter чему изначально равна?

Comment: Глобальному фильтру который получается из catalog.smart.filter
Выведите в result_modifier.php 

`$floatfilter = ${$arParams['FILTER_NAME']}; echo("<pre>");print_r($floatfilter);echo("</pre>");`

Естественно надо чтобы был задан фильтр.

почитайте документацию по методу думаю станет понятней:
[ссылка](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php)

Comment: $floatfilter = ${$arParams['FILTER_NAME']}; echo("<pre>");print_r($floatfilter);echo("</pre>"); ничего не выводит

Comment: А куда вы его вставили ? Плюс фильт задан ?

Comment: Добавлял на странице вызова компонента catalog.section. Фильтр получается надо задать с $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"]?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ofsf9v - вас выставлен параметр у фильтра и у catalog.section "FILTER_NAME" они должны совпадать. http://prntscr.com/ofsgog - если после фильтра поставить вывод глобального массива (в примере это nameFilter) то у Вас должны вывестись данные которые обработал фильтр. Так же этот глобальный параметр можно вывести и в компоненте catalog.section таким же образом http://prntscr.com/ofshu4.

Comment: $floatfilter = ${$arParams['FILTER_NAME']} такое выражение ничего не выводит, а такая $floatfilter = $GLOBALS[$arParams['FILTER_NAME']];  выдает массив фильтра

Comment: извините пропустил нужно при записи 
$floatfilter = ${$arParams['FILTER_NAME']}
нужно сначала обьявить глобальную переменную global ${$arParams['FILTER_NAME']}

Comment: if($floatfilter["OFFERS"]) здесь не приходит массив OFFERS

Comment: У вас свойства торговых предложений установлены в фильтрации. То есть у нас товары различаются по размеру или цвету. Чтобы в фильтре появился массив OFFERS нужно чтобы был в ФИЛЬТРЕ выбран либо размер или цвет.

Comment: Но мне нужно, чтобы фильтрация была по цене у торговых предложений

Comment: а как в итоге решили обрабатывать. Код можете прислать (скрин хотябы)

Comment: Сейчас в result_modifier.php перемещаю массив предложений в общий массив товаров http://prntscr.com/oisrge